# Does Back In Time recognise moved and deleted files?

Tags: software-recommendation, backup, sync, rsync

I'm looking for a full backup-solution currently and Back In Time seems to be a simple GUI-based program that is recommended a lot.

However, I'm not sure if Back In Time is the right solution for me. I have around 2,5 GB of project data on my computer that I want to have backed up and a 4 TB external hard drive for backups. However, if Back In Time keeps different versions of the files, even if they are deleted on the original medium or moved to a different directory in the case of temporary files, that needed space could multiply quickly.

Can Back In Time recognise that files have been deleted from a directory or moved to another location? Or would I basically have to manage two drives and clean up the backups manually as well?

I suppose that Back In Time could fill my backup drive quickly with obsolete uncompressed video files of a few GB each or something similar. Is there any good practice to handle backups of such files or should I use another tool?